# HTML <audio> element does not get into readyState 4 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio, readystate

I have separate `<audio>` and `<video>` elements on my web page and I want them to start playing at the same time when both of them can be played without interruption (i.e. have their `readyState` set to 4). Now I am using the following code:

```
// this.audio is <audio>
// this.video is <video>

var ap = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", (e) => {
        e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee)
        resolve()
    })
    this.audio.load()
})

var vp = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", (e) => {
        e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee)
        resolve()
    })
    this.video.load()
})

Promise.all([ap, vp]).then(() => {
    this.audio.play()
    this.video.play()
})
```

This works perfectly in Chromium and Opera browsers, but almost always fails in Firefox. The reason for this is that `<audio>` gets stuck in `readyState == 3` no matter how long I wait. And hence it never fires `canplaythrough` event (which requires `readyState == 4`).

Though the `<video>` element gets in `readyState == 4` almost instantly. Is it a Firefox bug or am I doing something wrong?

My version of Firefox is 51.0a2.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when using a video element with different sources.

For example, when using a `<track>` element Firefox will only set `readyState` to anything above 4 if the `<track>` element can be successfully loaded. In my case the track was just a dummy with an empty `src`. Therefore Firefox deemed that the video is not ready and 
`readyState` was stuck on 2.

```
<video autoplay controls>
      <source src="resource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="resource.webm" type="video/webm">
      <track id="vidTrack" kind="subtitles" src="" default>
</video>
```

**As soon as I removed the track from the video element, Firefox started playing the video immediately.**